# d3 Sankey - Is it possible to affect or decide the placement of nodes?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, sankey-diagram

I'm working with the Sankey plugin for d3.js. Is there a way to affect the automatic placement of the nodes?

If you compare the below 2 images.

Automatically generated Sankey Diagram: https://files.secureserver.net/0s3DEU5s3OZtqL

[image]

After I have manually re-arranged it: https://files.secureserver.net/0sYJF1w7f54wdF

[image]

You see that the nodes are aligned centered after each other which make it hard to use the diagram until you manually rearrange the nodes. Can I affect this flow somehow - or is it just the way it is?

By the way - Is there a way to specify that the text for the nodes should not be longer than the height of the nodes?

Comment: Have you managed to find any solution to make the placement better?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [demo](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/) and its explanation, there is no way to affect the placement (and a brief look at the source confirms that). Similarly, there's no way to specify that the text for the nodes should not be longer than the height of the nodes.