# How to assign the x-axis position of a node in a Sankey Diagram (D3) from the json file

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, sankey-diagram

I finally found a Sankey Diagram in D3 that allows movement of the nodes across the x-axis, but I would like to assign a value from the json file to fix the position in particular places.

http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/raw/5028304/

What I am trying to do is use the Sankey Diagram as a timeline.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21539265/d3-sankey-charts-manually-position-node-along-x-axis ?

Comment: Interesting concept of mixing timeline and sankey diagram! +1!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us call the x-coordinate `layer`. `layer=0` will be left edge, and `layer=n` will be the right edge. In your `JSON` file, in the `nodes` field, add the key-value pair `"layer": your_desired_x_as_integer` for each node.

Then go the sankey.js file and find the function `componentsByBreadth.forEach`.
Replace the line `node.x = component.x + node.x;` with:

```
if (node.layer) node.x=node.layer;
else node.x = component.x + node.x;
```

You can defined density of layers like this also, e.g. nodes placed on layers 0,1,2 or 0,4,8 will have a central node and two on the edges of the width of the sankey, but 0,1,5 will not have.

If you need more help, this feature, among many other is included in my D3 Sankey app: http://sankey.csaladen.es