# too many collisions in D3 Sankey when x-Position of nodes is fixed

Tags: d3.js

I adopted the trick from

[d3 sankey charts - manually position node along x axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21539265/d3-sankey-charts-manually-position-node-along-x-axis)

to manually control the x-position of my nodes. But many of the links end up crossing over each other: 
[image]

(I set the node widths to zero). I know a Sankey diagram with no link overlaps can be achieved, because the data corresponds to a dendrogram.

Increasing the number of iterations in the .layout(...) command does not solve the problem. Can someone please help?

Comment: Have you found an answer to this yet?

Comment: No, I have not found a solution yet.

Comment: If you do, please keep us up to date, I'd like to know this as well. I'll also keep an eye out for a solution.