# d3.js Sankey Chart: Manually Position SINKS Along X Axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sankey-diagram

The stackoverflow community has a great solution for moving nodes in a sankey chart along the x axis (link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21540569/4245462)).

However, I noticed one cannot manually change the position of **sink** nodes (i.e. those nodes auto-assigned to the far-right).  Because I am incorporating time into the sankey graph, I need to have certain sink nodes fixed at manually specified x positions.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88Akd/163/) example that needs this capability.  Specifically, I need `node "6": "Departed (6 mo.)"` to be fixed to the x position '1'.

```
"nodes":[
    ...
    {"node":6,"name":"Departed (6 mo.)","xPos":1},  // <-- need to move to position x=1; manual override not taking effect
    ...
```

Per the above-mentioned solution, I have updated `computeNodeBreadths()` within `d3.sankey()` and have included `"xPos":1` within the node of interest; but the change is not taking effect.

Does anyone have a recommended update to the above-mentioned solution that allows one to manually adjust **sink** node x positions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, the answer is to comment out the line `moveSinksRight(x)` within the `d3.sankey()` method `computeNodeBreadths()`.  Credit goes to Greg Ross: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21540569/4245462