# R network plot with node types fixed in columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, networkd3

I have two data frames that look like this:

```
y1 <- c(1, 0, 0) 
y2 <- c(0, 1, 0) 
y3 <- c(0, 0, 1) 
df1 <- data.frame(y1, y2, y3, row.names = c("x1", "x2", "x3"))

y1 <- c(1, 0, 0) 
y2 <- c(1, 0, 0) 
y3 <- c(1, 0, 0) 
df2 <- data.frame(y1, y2, y3, row.names = c("z1", "z2", "z3"))
```

I want to graph the relationships in these dataframes so that the x, y, and z values appear in columns with lines connecting them. Here's a rough example of what I'm looking to achieve:

[image]

I considered using a ggplot2 scatterplot with a categorical variable on the X axis to generate the columns, but I couldn't figure out how to generate the connecting lines between points from that. I also looked into ggnet2 for a network plot, but couldn't find any examples where nodes were fixed in columns.

EDIT:

My real use case has approximately 20 x points, 120 y points and 200 z points, so ideally the solution would scale fairly easily.

I attempted the following solution using a sankeynetwork plot from the networkD3 package

```
library(networkD3)
Nodes <- data.frame(name = c("x1", "x2", "x3", "y1", "y2", "y3", "z1", 
         "z2", "z3"), group = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", 
         "3"))
Links <- data.frame(source = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), target = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 
         6, 6), value = 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

sankeyNetwork(Links = Links, Nodes = Nodes, Source = "source",
          Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeGroup = "group", NodeID 
          = "name", sinksRight = FALSE)
```

[image]

The result is sort of correct... however it is probably not ideal. Additionally there doesn't seem to be a clear way of forcing z2 and z3 to appear with z1 on the right side of the page without going into the underlying javascript, which I have no idea how to do (see [d3 sankey charts - manually position node along x axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21539265/d3-sankey-charts-manually-position-node-along-x-axis))

Is there a better solution, or a way to improve this one?

Thanks!

Comment: `networkD3` is not ideal for what you're trying to do here. The concept of `networkD3` is that it *automatically* determines ideal layouts for network data... so all these questions (in general on SO) regarding manually adjusting or determining the position of elements and such are trying to achieve the opposite of what it was designed for. I haven't used them much, but I think @bdemarest's suggestion to use `igraph` or `ggraph` is a better choice for you... my impression is that they better facilitate the manual control you want.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible solution using `geom_segment` to draw the connecting edges. I don't how adaptable it will be to datasets larger or more complex than your example. I suspect there is a more graceful and scalable way to handle this with `igraph` or `ggraph`.

```
# Start with two data.frames: one for node positions,
# and one for edges you want to draw between nodes.

pos_dat = data.frame(node_id=paste(rep(c("x", "y", "z"), each=3), 
                                   rep(c("1", "2", "3"), times=3),
                                   sep=""),
                     type=rep(c("x", "y", "z"), each=3),
                     xpos=rep(c(1, 2, 3), each=3),
                     ypos=rep(c(1, 2, 3), times=3))

#   node_id type xpos ypos
# 1      x1    x    1    1
# 2      x2    x    1    2
# 3      x3    x    1    3
# 4      y1    y    2    1
# 5      y2    y    2    2
# 6      y3    y    2    3
# 7      z1    z    3    1
# 8      z2    z    3    2
# 9      z3    z    3    3


edge_dat = data.frame(start=c("x1", "x2", "x3", "y1", "y2", "y3"),
                        end=c("y1", "y2", "y3", "z1", "z1", "z1"))

#   start end
# 1    x1  y1
# 2    x2  y2
# 3    x3  y3
# 4    y1  z1
# 5    y2  z1
# 6    y3  z1
```

---

```
# Use two successive merges to join node x,y positions
# for each edge you want to draw.

tmp_dat = merge(edge_dat, pos_dat, by.x="start", by.y="node_id")
seg_dat = merge(tmp_dat, pos_dat, by.x="end", by.y="node_id")

# Remove unneeded columns and change column names for convenience.
seg_dat$type.x = NULL
seg_dat$type.y = NULL
names(seg_dat) = c("end", "start", "x", "y", "xend", "yend")

seg_dat
#   end start x y xend yend
# 1  y1    x1 1 1    2    1
# 2  y2    x2 1 2    2    2
# 3  y3    x3 1 3    2    3
# 4  z1    y1 2 1    3    1
# 5  z1    y2 2 2    3    1
# 6  z1    y3 2 3    3    1
```

---

```
# Finally, draw the plot.

library(ggplot2)

p = ggplot() +
    geom_segment(data=seg_dat, aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend),
                 colour="grey50") +
    geom_point(data=pos_dat, aes(x=xpos, y=ypos, colour=type), size=10) +
    geom_text(data=pos_dat, aes(x=xpos, y=ypos, label=node_id)) +
    scale_colour_manual(values=c(x="steelblue", y="darkorange", z="olivedrab3"))

ggsave("plot.png", plot=p, height=4, width=6, dpi=150)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts here. I agree, though, that this might not scale up as well as I need it to. My actual example has 19 x points, 112 y points and 131 z points. I'll make sure I clarify this in my question.